# Ajax requests executing 3 times rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I made a small admin system for a local gym where they can control payments, attendance, mailing, sales etc. Everything works fine except when they take attendance. It's an ajax function that gets executed 3 times. It does not always happen. My guess is that it has something to do with caches.
Here's the code for the specific ajax request:

```
 $( "#attendance" ).click( function( ) {
      var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
      var box_id = pathArray[2];
      var id = $('#number').val();


        $.ajax( {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/register_attendance",
                    data: {id:id, box_id:box_id}


              });
      } );
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
      if(e.which == 13) {
        var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
      var box_id = pathArray[2];
      var id = $('#number').val();


        $.ajax( {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/register_attendance",
                    data: {id:id, box_id:box_id}


              });
      }
    });
```

They can get the attendance registered by either pressing enter or the "Take Attendance" button.
I tried to restrict to only one attendance per day. that was my original solution but they have athletes coming twice per day and they want to register that too.

Here is my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery-tablesorter
//= require jquery-tablesorter/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager
//= require jquery.validate
//= require jquery.validate.additional-methods
//= require jquery.validate.localization/messages_es
//= require cocoon
//= require moment
//= require fullcalendar
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require raphael
//= require morris
//= require_tree
```

any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean it gets executed 3 times?

Comment: Enter on a button causes click....

Comment: You're probably adding the `click` and `keypress` event listeners multiple times, make sure this code is not inside a loop or the callback function of another event listener.

Comment: @epascarello it calls the ajax function three times in a row...

Comment: @Titus the thing is it does not always happen. It's totally random when it happens. I have tried by clicking the button or pressing the enter key and both "sometimes" fire the function 3 times

Comment: How are you including the JavaScript?

Comment: That part of code is inside static_pages.js file. It loads every time a new page is loaded. I haven't been able to solve it. It looks like a Cache problem. Because it's not always. I haven't found a certain patter when it happens @DomChristie

Comment: Could you show the code of how you're including that file? E.g. where in the page you're including it and any logic surrounding it

Comment: @DomChristie It's a rails app, so everything is added in the assets pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is intermittent, my suspicion is that you're running into a key-repeat issue actually, and that the triggering event is simply firing multiple times.

You may also want to call `e.preventDefault();` on your `keypress` handler.

Also look into throttling (ex. https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce), a technique for only allowing a function to execute every so often, so that you eliminate or at least reduce these kinds of accidental repeats.

Alternatively, depending on the details here, you may want to disable the attendance link as the first step after a click. This can also prevent duplicate clicks.

Comment: When you say disable the link, should I disable it via javascript or via rails?

Comment: In Javascript. I'm speaking about the client inhibiting itself from sending too many requests, basically